# Angular NG-ZORRO. How to split the component into templates

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd, ngtemplateoutlet

I am just starting with Angular. And I used ng-ZORRO.

1. I copy the example of ng-zorro. It works well.
2. I split it into templates using ng-template and ngTemplateOutlet. It doesn't work.

See my example about Menu.

- Menu1, Menu2 are normal codes. It works.
- Menu3, I use the ng-template. It doesn't work.

Please help me.

stackblitz link:
[https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-ivy-5reyrg](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-ivy-5reyrg?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

you have not imported the service necessary for the nz-menu-item directive to work, so the entry is not displayed